# Change screen resolution detection timeout

Tags: 12.10, xorg, display, resolution, kvm-switch

I'm using a KVM switch for using two laptops.
One is connected to Ubuntu 12.10.
The problem I have, is that every time I switch to the other PC, Ubuntu changes the resolution back to the integral laptop monitor.
When I switch back to work again with Ubuntu, I have to wait ~5 seconds until the screen resolution is detected again.

I figured out, the once I'm back on Ubuntu, if I open System Settings->Displays. it changes to the correct resolution instantly.

There's must be some sort of timeout that occurs that forces resolution change.
Can i configure this timeout value somewhere ?

**Updates**: problem occurs also on Ubuntu 12.04, and on PC (not laptop)

Comment: Kerenel Virtual Machine? What is KVM?

Comment: Have you tried leaving displays open?

Comment: @PyRulez http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch

Comment: Try: Open `Displays` (from unity), tick *Mirror displys option*

Comment: Do you have an `nvidia` card?

Comment: @falconer nope, does it matter ?

Comment: [This](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/linux.debian.user/iKkJA5mjbSQ) has a suggestion for nvidia-cards with similar (though not the same) problem. Namely to save the EDID of the monitor and feed it directly to the driver instead of querying it from the monitor. I think maybe a similar trick would help in your case. But if you don't use the nvidia driver I don't know how to feed in the EDID info into the driver. (Getting the EDID info is not problem, `xrandr --verbose` prints it out, just feeding it back.)

Answer (score 0):

Hard coding xorg.conf is the usual way to sort out these kinds of issues. Every time a screen change is being detected it is automatically reconfiguring the display settings on the fly.